# Как сделать, что бы бот отвечал на нажатие inline-кнопки в беседе в airogram?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Есть небольшой код и мне нужно, что бы при нажатии inline-кнопки, бот отвечал не в лс участнику, а в беседу, как это сделать?
Код:

```
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardRemove, ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton

bot = Bot(token=token)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
@dp.message_handler(content_types='text')
async def new_message(message: types.Message):
    if message.text == 'Бот дуэль':
        player_1 = f'<a href="t.me/{message.from_user.username}">{message.from_user.first_name}</a>'
        player_2 = f'<a href="t.me/{message.reply_to_message.from_user.username}">{message.reply_to_message.from_user.first_name}</a> '
        if message.from_user.id == message.reply_to_message.from_user.id:
            await message.reply(f'{player_1}, к сожалению, невозможно предложить играть самому себе...', parse_mode='HTML', disable_web_page_preview=True)
        else:
            inline_kb_full = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
            inline_btn_1 = InlineKeyboardButton('Дуэль да', callback_data='btn1')
            inline_btn_2 = InlineKeyboardButton('Дуэль нет', callback_data='btn2')
            inline_kb_full.add(inline_btn_1, inline_btn_2)
            await message.reply(f'{player_2}, минуточку внимания...\n{player_1} предложил вам дуэль\nВыберите ниже "Дуэль да" или "Дуэль нет", что бы принять вызов или отказаться', parse_mode='HTML', disable_web_page_preview=True, reply_markup=inline_kb_full)@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'btn1')
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'btn1')
async def new_message(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'Игрок принял вызов')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text='btn1')
async def new_message(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await call.answer()
    await call.message.answer("Игрок принял вызов")
```

Comment: Пишет ошибку, что отсутствует обязательный аргумент

Comment: Обновил, у вас у колбека почему-то был месседж

Comment: Все работает, но у вас была небольшая ошибка в types.CallbackQuerry, нужно использовать одну "R"